# How do you create a Kolmogorov-Smirnov chart in python for a 2 sample string lists?

Tags: python, charts, statistics, statistical-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am having difficulty in creating a Kolmogorov-Smirnov chart for 2 sample string lists that will display Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)?

As shown in [Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

I have been able to calculate the `Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.12939662567915355, pvalue=0.4183080902726968)` for the overall string lists however the difficulty is how to chart this that will display the Cumulative Frequency Distribution (CFS)

**Data List Samples**

Subset of List 1 e.g. `['team', 'new', 'estate', 'ho', 'ur', 'la', 'pak', 'ebay', 'biz', 'best']`

Subset of List 2 e.g. `['ilsilenzio', 'stilllife', 'mathiasboe', 'achininimeshikaratnasiri', 'andrewdabeka', 'davekhodabux', 'lilytermetz', 'marianhorsley', 'lindacloutier', 'moniquehoogland',]`

**Get the data lists**

```
    def getWikidataList():
    with open('./file1.csv', 'r') as f:
        read = csv.reader(f) 
        next(read)
        for line in read:
            lineitem = line[0].split()[0]
            item1 = process_text(lineitem)
            wikidatalist.append(item1[0])
        return wikidatalist


def getTwitterList1():
    with open('file2.csv', 'r') as f:
        read = csv.reader(f) 
        next(read)
        for line in read:
            lineitem = line[0].split()[0]
            item1 = process_text(lineitem)
            twitterdatalist.append(item1[0])
        return twitterdatalist



wikidatalist = getWikidataList()
twitterData = getTwitterList1()
```

**Plot the CDFs**

```
def ks_plot_comp(data_1, data_2):

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
    plt.plot(data_1, np.linspace(0, 1, len(data_1), endpoint=False))
    plt.plot(data_2, np.linspace(0, 1, len(data_2), endpoint=False))
    plt.legend('top right')
    plt.legend(['wikidata', 'twitterdata'])
    plt.title('Comparing 2 CDFs for KS-Test')
    plt.show()    
    ks_plot_comp(wikidatalist, twitterData)
```

[image]

Comment: I just reviewed an edit to this question. I recognized, that there is still a formatting issue in the last function. Can anyone fix that please? (I can't at the moment, because the edit is still pending and I already approved it)

Comment: @Ploly: now you can post your image ;-)

Comment: Hi Zoe & ASh, Thanks so much for correcting my mistake.I can't seem to post the image as my reputation has been reduced to a 7. It was one mistake... 4 points .... really?

Comment: Maybe you should post your image now ;-) Sorry, I don't know why there are so may people who like to downvote here. For some it seems to be a hobby.

Comment: Thanks so much jottbe. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, sorry that I can't help you with your original problem.